# C: const vs no const ..how come this compiles?

Tags: c, constants

I have a simple C function which I declare as:

```
int strLen(const char* str_)
{
  str_ = (char*) 0;
  return 0;
}
```

I was very surprised that that compiles! Why is that?

Whereas this onedoesn't compile (which makes sense):

```
int str(const int i_)
{
  i_ = 0;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because `const char* str_` says that str_ is a pointer to const characters.

You can change str_ itself, but not what it points to.

```
int strLen(const char* str_)
{
  str_ = (char*) 0; /* allowed */
  str_[0] = '\0'; /* not allowed */
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: More importantly, this pointer was taken by *value*, the original function does absolutely nothing!

Comment: rlbond makes an important point, in C arguments are passed by value so if the function modifies its arguments, no change is seen outside of that function.

Answer (score 11):

In the first one, you are changing what the pointer `str_` points to; the pointer `str_` is not const; it just points to const data.  You can make the pointer const as follows:

```
int strLen(const char* const str_)
```

Answer (score 6):

This follows the conventions of C declarations,

```
char *str;
```

means that `*str` will give you a `char` (or in other words, `str` is a pointer-to-a-char). Similarly,

```
const char *str;
```

means that `*str` will give you a `const char`, or in other words, `str` is a pointer-to-a-constant-char. So, you are not allowed to change `*str`, but you may change `str`.

If you want to make `str` itself `const`, use the following syntax:

```
char *const str;
```

Comment: and use `const char * const str;` to make everything constant, or is it `char const * const str` ? another inconsistency in C... (actually, the 2 declarations are equivalent)